# More than one docker daemon can use same location in different computers these have same storage disk?

Tags: docker

I created a storage pool. PCs use same disk for storage. Docker is installed in one computer and data-root is set to the storage disk.
I want to install docker to second computer and use same data-root to access same docker data coming from first computer. Is that possible?

Thank you.